# how to do open api format yaml validation, without using clusters?

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml, cloud, devops

I have build a schema in open api format:

```
type Test_manifest struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta
    metav1.ObjectMeta
    Spec spec
}

type spec struct {
    Policies  []string
    Resources resources
    Results   []results
    Variables variables
}
```

This is not complete schema, just a part of it.
And here below is the actual yaml file:

```
apiVersion: cli.kyverno.io/v1beta1
kind: kyvernotest
metadata:
  name: test-check-nvidia-gpus
  labels:
    foolabel: foovalue
  annotations:
    fookey: foovalue
```

I'm trying to validate this incoming yaml file from the user, I can convert this yaml to json and then validate the value of the fields, but I'm not getting how to validate the field itself, I mean if user write `name1` rather than `name` then how to show error on it. Basically how to validate the key.

Here's what I've implemented for value validation:

```
test := "cmd/cli/kubectl-kyverno/test/test.yaml"
    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(test)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: failed to read file %v", err)
    }
    policyBytes, err1 := yaml.ToJSON(yamlFile)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to convert to JSON")
    }
    tests := &kyvernov1.Test_manifest{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(policyBytes, tests); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to decode yaml")
    }
    if tests.TypeMeta.APIVersion == "" {
        fmt.Printf("skipping file as tests.TypeMeta.APIVersion not found")
    }
    if tests.TypeMeta.Kind == "" {
        fmt.Printf("skipping file as tests.TypeMeta.Kind not found")
    } else if tests.TypeMeta.Kind != "KyvernoTest" {
        fmt.Printf("skipping file as tests.TypeMeta.Kind is not `KyvernoTest`")
    }
```

Also we want this valiadtion to happen outside the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to my mind:

1. I notice that you are trying to build a k8s API extension manually which is a lot of rework, I will suggest you use a framework which will handle this for you. This is the recommended best practice that is used very frequently. It is too complicated to be done manually. Here are some resources. ([kube-builder](https://book.kubebuilder.io/), [operator-sdk](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/build/)). These solution are Open-API based as well. They will let you define your schema in a simple template, and generate all the validation and API + controller code for you.
2. If you want more validation and sanity testing, typically this is done with the help of an admission controller in your cluster. It intercepts the incoming request, and before it is processed by the API server, performs actions on it. (For verification, compliance, policy enforcement, authentication etc.) You can read more about admission controllers [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/).

Comment: But the problem is I want to validate this yaml without using cluster, and kubebuilder will generate crds and cluster will be required fot that

Comment: Also I'm not trying to build a k8s extension, this schema is different from k8s

Comment: You will have to generate an API server anyway, to host this API that you are developing and from the name `kubectl-kyverno` tells me you plan to use it later in a k8s environment.

Comment: actually it will be used in cli, so don't need any server, and yes this cli will also be used in k8s env, but it should also work locally, So user will define this yaml somewhere, and then apply the cli cmd, so the cmd will only exceute when the yaml is valid.